# Regex for matching domains (.com)

Tags: regex, text, dns

I'm trying to match all domains in a string for example:

```
"hello.test.com"
'hello-to.ya.com'
"test.two.for.com"
```

Basically matching all characters between single and double quotes that have .com

Here's what I came up with:
`\.([a-z0-9-])+\.(com)`

I'm testing with this visual site:
https://regexr.com/

But it won't match example #3 and I want to search for the outer quotes too. I'm parsing JSON in string format, so I don't want extra stuff.

Example JSON:

```
'DbiResourceId': 'db-ZDKG55HDKSLJ33',
                  'DeletionProtection': False,
                  'DomainMemberships': [],
                  'Endpoint': {'Address': 'things-dev.dj5fhdk2.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
                               'HostedZoneId': 'DKGH32DL4',
                               'Port': 1234},
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can not match domains just by analyzing the string, hence no regex will match all cases. You have either to restrict your problem space, or use the Public Suffix List, or use live DNS queries to find the delegation cuts. Examples: `dk` is both a domain and hostname (it resolves), `www.example.uk.com` is either domain `example.uk.com` or `uk.com` depending on how you want to see it, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex only matches a portion of all 3 of your examples. If you need to match the URL in its entirety, then you want a pattern that matches one or more substrings of the form `[a-z0-9-]+\.` followed by the substring `com`. That would look like:

```
([a-z0-9-]+\.)+com
```

You can play with it on [regexr](https://regexr.com/4q2au). You can add the outer single quotes if you want to match those:

```
'([a-z0-9-]+\.)+com'
```

> **NOTE:** I used your basic collection of characters for these regex expressions to help you get started, and it looks like you're doing "just enough to get by" with your particular application. However, these do not capture all valid URL names, and they do
> allow some invalid names (*e.g.*, some that begin with `-`). If
> you want to make this more accurate to the URL standard, you need to have a look at the
> [RFC 3986, section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2).
> This describes in detail the valid characters allowed in a URL name.

Comment: This will have a ton of false positives. `-.com`, `-a.com`, `a-.com` for example will all be mached as valid, while in fact they are not valid domains due to DNS rules on names syntax.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes I'm aware of that. I was getting the basic idea down for the op for the regex. I'll edit my answer to improve the regex.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you're asking in your question.

If you want:

```
"hello.test.com"
"hello-to.ya.com"
"test.two.for.com"
```

to match on

```
test.com
ya.com
for.com
```

excluding the sub domains, try:

```
([a-z0-9-]*.com)
```

Use the multi line and global flag.